# excel does not respond after VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am new on VBA Macros. After having run this macro, that, actually starts when you open it, excel does not respond. This macro is intended to clean html files. The goal is to clean and convert the html files in xlsx files so I can convert them in .csv via python. All the lines of this code are commented.

I am writing something because i am not allowed to write just code. Today is a sunny day and everything goes well. Except for the macro that is not running.

Please provide me support.

Thank you

```
Sub SaveFile(FileName As String)
'declare variables
Dim InitLocation As String
Dim FileFormat
 
    'specify the location where the new files will be saved
    InitLocation = "\\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\FADP\FADP Monthly Bucket\CSV\"
    'specify the format we will be saving as
    FileFormat = ".xlsx"
    'save the workbook under specified location, specified format, with name provided when function is called
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=InitLocation & FileName & FileFormat, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    
End Sub
 
Sub DeleteRowsMcr()
 
'delete rows we dont need
    Range("A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7").EntireRow.Delete
 
End Sub
 
 
Sub openMyfile()
'Declare variables
Dim InitLocation As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim Extension As String
Dim FileNo As Integer
Dim FileName As String
 
'specify what to do in case of error'
On Error GoTo errhndl
 
'hide warnings (like extension being wrong etc - so that no manual actions are required)
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
 
'start numerating the files
FileNo = 1
    

InitLocation = "\\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\FADP\FADP Monthly Bucket\"
 

StrFile = Dir(InitLocation)
 
'extension that we will be checking for
Extension = "xls"
 
'a loop that goes through files in the provided path (until no files are left)
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
 
'check if the extenstion matches the required one
    If LCase(Right(StrFile, 3)) = Extension Then
        'open the file
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=InitLocation & StrFile
        'numerate to the next file
        StrFile = Dir()
        'wait for the above to finish
        DoEvents
        'prepare name of the file which will be used when saving it
        FileName = "FixedExcel_" & FileNo
        'call macro to delete unwanted rows
        Call DeleteRowsMcr
        'Save the file under the prepared name, inside location specified in the function SaveFile
        Call SaveFile(FileName)
        'Close the workbook that has just been saved
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        'numerate for the next filename
        FileNo = FileNo + 1
    End If
Loop
 
'Bring back the warning
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
 
'try to quit the file
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
 
'end the macro - skipping the below error message
End
 
'in case of error go to this line
errhndl:
MsgBox "An error has occured, please check if the files are available and accessible"
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'automatically call the macro when workbook is opened
    Call openMyfile
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `StrFile = Dir()` line is inside an `If` statement, so if the condition isn't met, `StrFile` never advances, which can cause an infinite loop. I recommend moving the `StrFile = Dir()` line outside the If statement, just before the end of the loop block.

Comment: Side node, good comments say *why*, and let the code say *what*. Consider deleting the redundant comments that plainly restate what the code already says, and renaming things to use more meaningful names when the code isn't speaking as clearly as it could.

Comment: You don't want `End`, you want `Exit Sub`. `End` doesn't "end a macro", it completely nukes the entire runtime context, wiping out any global state you might be having. This *will* cause problems sooner or later.

Comment: Add your "Bring back the warning" section of code to your errhndl.  That way if your code fails, all of your warnings, screen updating etc. all get turned back on.